# Pybrain gives wrong percentage of error

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I trained pybrain on a huge dataset consisting of 3600 patterns and tried to test in on another similar dataset. The percentage error shown was 0.0277, however the predicted output was simply an array of 1s which completely differs from the original output.

```
df = pandas.read_csv('BOM-DEL.csv').groupby('x').mean().reset_index()[:3600]
dk = pandas.read_csv('BLR-DEL.csv').groupby('x').mean().reset_index()
dx = numpy.array((dk.x-numpy.amin(dk.x))/(numpy.amax(dk.x)-numpy.amin(dk.x))
dy = numpy.array((dk.y-numpy.amin(dk.y))/(numpy.amax(dk.y)-numpy.amin(dk.y))
dx1 = numpy.array((df.x-numpy.amin(df.x))/(numpy.amax(df.x)-numpy.amin(df.x))
dy1 = numpy.array((df.y-numpy.amin(df.y))/(numpy.amax(df.y)-numpy.amin(df.y))
ds = ClassificationDataSet(1, 1 , nb_classes=3600)
dt = ClassificationDataSet(1,1, nb_classes=3600)
for k in xrange(len(dx)):
    ds.addSample(dx[k],dy[k])
    dt.addSample(dx1[k],dy1[k])
trndata = dt
tstdata = ds
fnn = buildNetwork( trndata.indim, 360 , trndata.outdim, outclass=SoftmaxLayer )
trainer = BackpropTrainer( fnn, dataset=trndata, momentum=0.1, learningrate=0.01 , verbose=True, weightdecay=0.01) 
trainer.trainEpochs (50)
print 'Percent Error on Test dataset: ' , percentError(     trainer.testOnClassData (
       dataset=tstdata )
       , tstdata['class'] )

numpy.array([fnn.activate(k) for k,_  in tstdata])
```

I get the following results:

```
>>> array([[1.0],[1.0]....[1.0])
Percentage error = 0.02
```

Although my output should range between 0.001 to 1

Can someone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Umm, is the problem about the percentage of error (based from the title), or the predicted output array (based from the content)? I admit I don't really understand much about machine learning... what if it's 0.02%, which is 0.002?

Comment: @AndrewT.   Both. I dont understand why is it showing so less percentage of error when the accuracy ~ 0% ? Also I wasn't expecting the predicted output to be completely wrong since I ot an error of 20% when I myself had implemented a naive backpropagation algorithm.